# Angular @Output not passing value to AppComponent?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass a loading boolean value from a child component to the AppComponent using @Output decorator but I'm not seeing the desired result.

funds-list.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-funds',
    templateUrl: './funds-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./funds-list.component.scss'],
    providers: [FundsService]
})
export class FundsListComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private fundsService: FundsService) { }

    @Output() LoadingChanged = new EventEmitter();

    funds: Fund[];

    ngOnInit() : void {

        this.fundsService.getFunds()
            .subscribe(funds => {
                this.LoadingChanged.emit(false);
                return this.funds = funds
            });
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

    // Sets initial value to true to show loading spinner on first load
    loading : boolean = true

    constructor(private authenticationService: AuthenticationService, private router: Router) {
        router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
            this.navigationInterceptor(event)
        })
    }

    LoadingChangedHandler(color:string) {
        this.loading = false
    }

    // Shows and hides the loading spinner during RouterEvent changes
    navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
            this.loading = true
        }
        // if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        //     this.loading = false
        // }

        // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the spinner in case a request fails
        if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
            this.loading = false
        }
        if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
            this.loading = false
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I've commented `event instanceof NavigationEnd`. When I uncomment this, the loading div disappears so it seems that the thing works provided loading is set to false.

app.component.html

```
...
<router-outlet (LoadingChanged)="LoadingChangedHandler($event)"></router-outlet>
<div class="loading" *ngIf="loading">Loading&#8230;</div>
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<router-outlet>` doesn't support bindings. You need to use a shared service (with an observable) to communicate with components added by the router.

Comment: The default @Output declaration is "...Change", not "...Changed" i think. I don't know if this makes a difference... But you could also check out Todd's stuff here: https://toddmotto.com/component-events-event-emitter-output-angular-2

Comment: Thanks. I went with a loading service and bound a public property of that to the loading div. Works pretty well and much simpler I guess.